# How to use MSSQL's user impersonation in Java using Tomcat connection pool?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, spring-boot, connection-pooling

In our application we are using Spring Boot and Tomcat connection pool manager. The connections are acquired using a specific user. So anyone who connects to the application regardless of their username, we use the application's username to persist data. However, for certain operation we want to impersonate using MSSQL command '[setuser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186297.aspx)'. How can we achieve this?

To make it more clear, what we want is some sort of interceptor so that before executing a sql statement we can execute this command:

```
setuser 'user_a'
```

and before releasing the connection we can execute:

```
setuser
```

so that impersonation resets.
Assume that in the interceptor we know whether the connection should be impersonated or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Jdbc interceptor. The method in the interceptor will be called whenever a connection is borrowed from the pool. Please check the below link:

[Jdbc interceptor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors)

Here is my code:

```
public class ImpersonatorJdbcInterceptor extends JdbcInterceptor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImpersonatorJdbcInterceptor.class);

    /**
     *  This method gets invoked whenever a connection is borrowed from the pool.
     *  Since releasing a connection back to pool cannot be intercepted in this method we
     *  need to first reset the previous impersonation.
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void reset(ConnectionPool connectionPool, PooledConnection pooledConnection) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        logger.debug("A connection is borrowed from the pool by {}", (auth != null ? auth.getName() : "null"));
        Connection conn = pooledConnection.getConnection();

        /*
         * Note:
         * 1 We can't impersonate current user
         * 2 We can't impersonate a user when the current session is already impersonated.
         * 3 'setuser' without username resets back to original user who has created the connection
         * 4 The user must have the right permission to be able to impersonate
         * 5 It is the caller's responsibility to close the connection; We only close the connection if this execution fails
         */
        try (PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(auth != null ? "setuser; setuser ?" : "setuser")) {
            if(auth != null) {
                prep.setString(1, auth.getName());
            }
            prep.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Impersonation failed. Please check permission for 'setuser': " + (auth != null ? auth.getName() : "null"), e);
            close(conn);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Oops! Cannot execute statements, please contact the administrator", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the statement and rolls back only if something goes wrong.
     * @param conn
     */
    private void close(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.rollback();
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Something went wrong and the connection cannot be closed", e);
            //the caller will throw exception
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Care to share your interceptor?

Comment: how do you know that the security context is reverted after the connection is returned to the pool?

Comment: It's managed by Spring... we are not setting it manually. So once the request is served the security holder will be cleared by Spring... I believe so!

Comment: I was talking about the JDBC connection to the SQL Server. The thread local is unaffected here.

Comment: sorry I don't get exactly what you mean. The user is already authenticated and security holder is populated by Spring and here I just get the username so I don't need to worry about that context to be reverted. This method - reset() - only gets called when the connection is borrowed. we have no access to when the connection is returned back to the pool

Comment: And that is exactly your problem. You set the user permanently for this pooled connection. The next borrow of this connection will have the previously set user in it. This is regardless of Spring Security.

Comment: But the next borrow is either the same user or new request from another user who is already authenticated and is running in a different thread